# How to handle mixed collections of objects in C++

Tags: c++, class, oop, parent-child, hierarchical-data

I'm working on a C++ hierarchical tree-based class design, with two object types, A and B.

Type A objects can have any number of children, of type either A or B, but they must be stored in a single sequential order. Type B objects may not have any children.

My question is regarding the best OO practices for handling collections of mixed types in C++.

One solution I can see would be to create a Base class, which from which both classes A and B are derived, and for A to hold a `vector<Base*> children`. This seems like a good solution except for down the line there is more likely to be some dynamic casting to determine child type, which I've been told can be a symptom of poor code design.

Another option would be for class A to hold a separate list of A and B children, along with a value to represent that child's position in the combined children list. This seems like a more problematic solution as when items are inserted, removed or rearranged, the position values must be manually maintained.

A third option would be to roll the functionality of classes A and B into one class and have a flag to note how to interpret the object.

Are these my only options for this problem? Am I missing some more elegant solution, or approaching it from the wrong direction? I've seen that Boost has some options for heterogenous collections but using Boost isn't an option in this project unfortunately.

**EDIT: I'll try to describe the real case with some more details**

Type A objects define collections. They hold string paths or patterns, to define a set of objects (from a user created pool). Children collections define further subets.

Type B objects are overrides. They describe operations to be applied to the set of objects defined by parent A objects.

The order of the collections and collections determines the order in which the overrides are applied.

The point where I was finding I needed to downcast was at an evaluation stage, where I was iterating through the tree to collate and apply the overrides - I needed to know how to treat each item in the tree and whether to look for location or override data. From the comments I've received it seems I should able to accomplish what I need with real OO design, so I'll have another go before I can equivocally say otherwise.

Comment: Why will you need to downcast in the first solution? What problem do you need to solve by this that you cannot solve via `virtual` functions (and polymorphism)?

Comment: Can you not implement GetType method in both A and B for the 1st solution to avoid dynamic casting?

Comment: @UnholySheep, if each class has some unique member functions, how can I access those from a base class pointer without downcasting?

Comment: @KillzoneKid are you meaning something like checking an enum from the GetType, then static cast based off the result? Is that better than a dynamic cast?

Comment: Why do your child classes have unique functions that you need to access directly? I find your example too abstract to tell what the real requirements (and usage) for `A` and `B` are. And while `dynamic_cast` should be avoided whenever possible there are some cases where it is necessary.

Comment: @UnholySheep maybe it is possible to design around not requiring direct access to those functions, I'll take a bit of a longer look to see if I can't get around that before I come back to you on that.

Comment: @Joe Yeah `if (base->GetType() == TypeA)...` I cannot answer whether it is better than dynamic cast because you didn't provide enough details of your design

Comment: You don't access unique stuff directly. You only call functions in Base (that are common to all derived classes) and *they* access unique stuff as needed.

Comment: How is the "single sequential order" defined?   In other words, what are the criteria in which a `A`s are ordered, `B`s are ordered, and an `A` is ordered before or after a `B`?

Comment: Designing your system in such a way that you only ever need to know about functions in Base is called "object oriented design". It is **not** called "designing around".

Comment: This sounds like a [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). What is it you want to do really?

Comment: @PasserBy, I mentioned the solutions I'd thought of to try and help describe my current understanding of the problem and how I could go about it, but like I said I'm trying to understand if I'm approaching it incorrectly, as it seems I am.

I'll edit the question with some more details of my case and see if that helps elucidate what I really want to do.

Answer (score 2):

With C++17, you might utilize [`std::variant`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant)

```
struct B {
// ...
};

struct A {
std::vector<std::variant<A, B> > children;
// ...
};
```

Comment: Thanks Olaf, good to know about that although here we can't even use C++11 yet. Hopefully that'll change soon, but I have to make do until then.

Answer (score 2):

None of your proposed solutions have anything to do with OO or polymorphism or any such buzzword. (Not that there's any inherent problem with that).

The OO solution would be to rely exclusively on **virtual functions** in `Base` to perform work specific to each particular derived class. Nothing more and nothing less.

Comment: So would you suggest having virtual functions in a base class that are specific to (or even only implemented by) each child class? Or should base class functions always be generic, but the data which is returned be interpreted differently based on their type (as provided by some GetType method)?

Comment: @Joe You are asking "how to write object-oriented software". This is way too broad. But no, no GetType. Each specific function is only implemented in specific derived class. You may have your Base functions pure virtual.